# How to increase MAX LCORES in DPDK

Tags: linux-kernel, dpdk

I am using dpdk 17.11.1, on a system with > 128 cores.
In the startup log, it is displayed that 128 cores are detected.

As I am interested in using lcores beyond 128 for the application, I tried
to increase the CONFIG_RTE_MAX_LCORES value in the dpdk/config/common_base
file, and recompliled dpdk, but it still detects a max of 128 cores.

I need to use higher numbered cores because the NIC card is plugged on to
CPU 6 so I want to use the cores local to CPU6 for better performance.

Please let me how the config_rte_max_lcore can be increased, and is there
any other change that needs to be made ?

Comment: Changing `RTE_MAX_LCORE` is the way to go. Does Linux report more than 128 cores?

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your response.   Yes, linux displays a total of 384 cores in my system. Can you point me to the file where RTE_MAX_LCORE value should be changed?.

Comment: If DPDK freshly cloned or unpacked, use `dpdk/config/common_base` as you mentioned. If DPDK has been configured (or built), there is a `build/.config` file.

Comment: Thank you :). I changes the config in .config and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Answer shared by @Andriy Berestovskyy is true:

> If DPDK freshly cloned or unpacked, use dpdk/config/common_base as you mentioned. If DPDK has been configured (or built), there is a `build/.config`.